# Permission denied for geckodriver.log only from Task Scheduler

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver, windows-task-scheduler

My script using Selenium and Firefox for a postal tracking service website gets the status of my item. Whenever there is an update I have it send me an email. It works fine from a batch file and on its own, but running it from Windows Task Scheduler returns :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\PycharmProjects\random\WhereIsMyItem.py", line 18, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 163, in __init__
    log_path=service_log_path)
  File "C:\Users\Sandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

The geckodriver.log, .exe, batch file and script are stored in the same directory.

My batch file :

```
start C:\Users\Sandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe -i C:\Users\Sandra\PycharmProjects\random\WhereIsMyItem.py
```

I tried configuring the geckofiles to be saved where Python is saved and Task Scheduler runs from my user with admin privileges. Anything else I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Upload your source code if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be related to the location of your geckodriver.exe.
One thing is certain the user in whose name the windows scheduled task is meant to run has no modify NTFS rights on the file geckodriver.log.
Geckodriver.log is normally created in the same subdirectory where the exe resides.
To my experience the geckodriver.exe will be found automatically if it is located anywhere available in the PATH.
Possible explanation: the script found a geckodriver.exe in the C root folder where the task running windows user has no sufficient access rights. (In this scenario an admin account is still not sufficient you have to explicitly set permissions in the file.)